# Access to key value of returned array from the ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Here my return json from my Ajax method :

> {"id_ac":"32","mail_uniq_ac":"mail@gmail.com","id_civ":"2"}

I would like to access to `id_ac` key value in my javascript but actually, I cannot.

this is my ajax controller :

```
public function executeAjaxGetActeur(sfWebRequest $request){
        $id_ac = $request->getParameter('id_ac');

        $acteur = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Acteur')->findOneByIdAc($id_ac);

        return $this->renderText(json_encode($acteur->toArray()));
    }
```

Here is my javascript where I need to get the key values

```
function showModalTempsPartenaire($id_ac){

        var $id_ac = $id_ac;
        $.post($url + "/ajax/get_acteur", {
            id_ac: $id_ac
        }, function (data) {
            if (data && trim(data) != '')
                console.log(data);
            console.log(data['id_ac'])
        });
}
```

The :

```
console.log(data);
```

Output me :

```
{"id_ac":"32","mail_uniq_ac":"mail@gmail.com","id_civ":"2"}
```

but console.log(data['id_ac']); return undifined

Comment: Use `console.log(data.id_ac)` instead.

Comment: Both work well.

Comment: Given `var data = {"id_ac":"32","mail_uniq_ac":"mail@gmail.com","id_civ":"2"};`, `console.log(data['id_ac'])` will output `32`...I'm afraid your data does not exactly look how you posted it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're encoding the data to JSON in the server side using `json_encode()`, you need to decode it in the client side using `JSON.parse()` so you will be able to get the information from it like :

```
function showModalTempsPartenaire($id_ac){
    var $id_ac = $id_ac;
    $.post($url + "/ajax/get_acteur", {
        id_ac: $id_ac
    }, function (data) {
        if (data && trim(data) != '')
            data = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(data['id_ac'])
    });
}
```

**Working sample**

```js
var data = '{"id_ac":"32","mail_uniq_ac":"mail@gmail.com","id_civ":"2"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(obj['id_ac']);
```